# running elastic search on heroku connect refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch on Heorku with the Bonsai add on but I keep getting the following error:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

and then this sometimes too

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 131ms (Searchkick: 5.7ms | ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

I've heard this is because it can't find the Bonsai URL but I believe i initiated that with /config/initializer/bonsai.rb

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL']
```

Any ideas? Basically the whole app has stopped working. It runs fine locally this is just on production.

I also have `gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.0.4'` installed but still not working.

I also went and re built the index, according to this and still the same error

```
    rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ curl -XPOST [MYURL]/pallet-index
    {"acknowledged":true}
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ curl -XPOST [MYURL]/hello -d '{"title":"Hello world"}'
    {"_index":"pallet-index","_type":"test","_id":"hello","_version":1,"created":true}
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ curl -XGET '[MYURL]/pallet-index/te 
    {"_index":"pallet-index","_type":"test","_id":"hello","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"title":"Hello world"}}
```

Comment: Can you try to run this before starting your process: `export BONSAI_URL=$(heroku config:get BONSAI)` You somehow need to set the `BONSAI_URL` env variable in order to be able to use it in your code.

Comment: @Val where/when should i run that? sorry super new to this all.

Comment: On the same machine where you run your client code.

Comment: @Val ok i did that and still getting the same error.

Comment: What do you get if you run `curl -XGET $(heroku config:get BONSAI)` in your shell?

Comment: @Val `rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ curl -XGET $(heroku config:get BONSAI)
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ `

Comment: woops, my bad, `curl -XGET $(heroku config:get BONSAI_URL)` (missed the `_URL` suffix). Please try again.

Comment: @Val no worries! appreciate your help with all of this. `rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (bonsai-more-more) $ curl -XGET $(heroku config:get BONSAI_URL)
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Link",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "[MYHASH}",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-29T22:19:18Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Comment: Much better! Now make sure that `BONSAI_URL` gets set and exported in the shell where you start your client application as shown in my first comment above.

Comment: @Val ok so just to confirm. 1) run `export BONSAI_URL=$(heroku config:get BONSAI)` 2) re push to heroku? unsure what to do after step 1

Comment: Run `export BONSAI_URL=$(heroku config:get BONSAI_URL)` but on the same host as your Ruby code runs.

Comment: @Val sorry my terminology is limited here. in the heroku shell? just unsure where to run that.

Comment: Where does your Ruby code run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105579/discussion-between-rs19-and-val).